# Option type encoding / robustness in Lisp

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, option-type, robustness

```
(define (nth n lst)
  (if (= n 1)
    (car lst)
    (nth (- n 1)
         (cdr lst) )))
```

is an unsafe partial function, `n` may go out of range. An `error` can be helpful,

```
(define (nth n lst)
  (if (null? lst)
    (error "`nth` out of range")
    (if (= n 1)
      (car lst)
      (nth (- n 1)
           (cdr lst) ))))
```

But what would a **robust** Scheme analogue to Haskell's `Maybe` data type look like?

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a

nth :: Int -> [a] -> Maybe a
nth _ []       = Nothing
nth 1 (x : _)  = Just x
nth n (_ : xs) = nth (n - 1) xs
```

Is just returning `'()` adequate?

```
(define (nth n lst)
  (if (null? lst) '()
    (if (= n 1)
      (car lst)
      (nth (- n 1)
           (cdr lst) ))))
```

Comment: I would think that signalling a runtime error is robust.

Comment: @rainer-joswig An `error` may not be *unexpected action*, but still classifies as *abnormal termination*. Nobody wants the Cassini orbiter to report an error.

Comment: Not necessary in Lisp, signalling an error may not terminate the program. A runtime out-of range call is abnormal. Handle it. You need to handle it anyway. 'Nobody wants the Cassini orbiter to report an error.' Why not? even spacecrafts have interfaces, logs, etc. Flight software needs to be able to deal with runtime errors, faulty hardware, conflicting computer results, etc. Real flight software accepts that there might be runtime problems and deals with it.

Comment: @rainer-joswig I don't think correspondence with a spacecraft 1.5 billion kilometers from Earth is a good plan B. "Dealing with it" automatically is kind of the point.

Comment: The recent rosetta space mission travelled 6 billion km. Quotes: 'We can upload new enhanced software at any time over the 12-year mission, and the software for each computer is interchangeable.' ' If the spacecraft is in serious trouble, it automatically goes into safe mode' 'Since memory patching is something that has to be done carefully, this is done in an interactive session'

Comment: @GeorgJohannSchubert What makes you think that the Common Lisp condition system does not allow you to deal with exceptional conditions under program control?  Because it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

### The direct equivalent would be to mimic the Miranda version:

```
#!r6rs
(library (sylwester maybe) 
  (export maybe nothing maybe? nothing?)
  (import (rnrs base))

  ;; private tag 
  (define tag-maybe (list 'maybe)) 

  ;; exported tag and features
  (define nothing (list 'nothing))

  (define (maybe? v)
    (and (pair? v) 
         (eq? tag-maybe (car v))))

  (define (nothing? v)
    (and (maybe? v)
         (eq? nothing (cdr v))))

  (define (maybe v)
    (cons tag-maybe v)))
```

How to use it:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs) (sylwester maybe))
(define (nth n lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) (maybe nothing))
        ((zero? n) (maybe (car lst)))
        (else (nth (- n 1) (cdr lst)))))

(nothing? (nth 2 '()))
; ==> #t
```

## Exceptions

```
(define (nth n lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) (raise 'nth-nothing))
        ((zero? n) (car lst))
        (else (nth (- n 1) (cdr lst)))))


(guard (ex
        ((eq? ex 'nth-nothing)
         "nothing-value"))
  (nth 1 '())) ; ==> "nothing-value"
```

## Default value:

```
(define (nth n lst nothing)
  (cond ((null? lst) nothing)
            ((zero? n) (car lst))
            (else (nth (- n 1) (cdr lst)))))

(nth 1 '() '()) 
; ==> '()
```

## Deault value derived from procedure

```
(define (nth index lst pnothing)
  (cond ((null? lst) (pnothing))
        ((zero? n) (car lst))
        (else (nth (- n 1) (cdr lst)))))

(nth 1 '() (lambda _ "list too short")) 
; ==> "list too short"
```

## Combination of exception and default procedure

Racket, a Scheme decent, often has a default value option that defaults to an exception or a procedure thunk. It's possible to mimic that behavior:

```
(define (handle signal rest)
  (if (and (not (null? rest))
           (procedure? (car rest)))
      ((car rest))
      (raise signal)))

(define (nth n lst . nothing)
  (cond ((null? lst) (handle 'nth-nothing nothing)) 
        ((zero? n) (car lst))
        (else (nth (- n 1) (cdr lst)))))

(nth 1 '() (lambda () 5)) ; ==> 5
(nth 1 '()) ; exception signalled
```

Answer (score 6):

It's easy to break your attempt. Just create a list that contains an empty list:

```
(define lst '((1 2) () (3 4)))
(nth 2 lst)
-> ()
(nth 100 lst)
-> ()
```

The key point that you're missing is that Haskell's `Maybe` doesn't simply return a bare value when it exists, it wraps that value. As you said, Haskell defines `Maybe` like so:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

**NOT** like this:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | a
```

The latter is the equivalent of what you're doing.

To get most of the way to a proper `Maybe`, you can return an empty list if the element does not exist, as you were, *but also* wrap the return value in another list if the element does exist:

```
(define (nth n lst)
  (if (null? lst) '()
    (if (= n 1)
      (list (car lst)) ; This is the element, wrap it before returning.
      (nth (- n 1)
           (cdr lst) ))))
```

This way, your result will be either an empty list, meaning the element did not exist, or a list with only one element: the element you asked for. Reusing that same list from above, we can distinguish between the empty list and a non-existant element:

```
(define lst '((1 2) () (3 4)))
(nth 2 lst)
-> (())
(nth 100 lst)
-> ()
```

Comment: Can this `<option> ::= "'()" | "(cons " <value> " '())"` encoding be considered the standard in robust Lisp programming? Is that even a thing?

Comment: @GeorgJohannSchubert I'm not sure if I'd call it the standard, but I also haven't been around that much Lisp. As a guess, I'd say it's probably not the standard as I don't think Option types are very commonly used in Lisp, but again, I could be wrong. I do think it's a good candidate to be promoted as the standard (but I'll refrain from claiming it's the best without studying the various Lisps type systems in more detail). Being that both variants are lists, it works well with standard functions like `map`, allowing you to perform operations without checking if there's actually a value or not.

Comment: @GeorgJohannSchubert One way to figure out if this is a good choice is to check with your teammates or friends to see if they can understand what you're doing and why, preferably with as little extra explanation on your part as possible. If they get it right away, you might be onto something. If they're confused, especially after an explanation, you may want to look for a more idiomatic approach (possibly that `error`).

Answer (score 3):

Another way to signal, that no matching element was found, would be to use multiple return values:

```
(define (nth n ls)
  (cond
    ((null? ls) (values #f #f))
    ((= n 1) (values (car ls) #t))
    (else (nth (- n 1) ls))))
```

This comes at the expense of being a little bit cumbersome for the users of this function, since they now have to do a

```
(call-with-values (lambda () (nth some-n some-list))
                  (lambda (element found?)
                     ... whatever ...))
```

but that can be alleviated by using some careful macrology. R7RS specifies the `let-values` syntax.

```
(let-values (((element found?) (nth some-n some-list)))
   ... whatever ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

As a non-lisper I really can't say how idiomatic this is, but you could return the [Church encoding](http://www.cbdumas.com/posts/church_encoding.html) of an option type:

```
(define (nth n ls)
  (cond
    ((null? ls) (lambda (default f) default))
    ((= n 1) (lambda (default f) (f (car ls))))
    (else (nth (- n 1) ls))))
```

But that's about as complicated to use as @Dirk's proposal. I'd personally prefer to just add a default argument to `nth` itself.